# How to COPY files from Docker CONTAINER into a Docker volume using COPY command

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I was using COPY command all this time to COPY stuff from HOST machine (eg my laptop) into the container.

Now i have a usecase where i want to copy the files that was generated inside the docker container into the docker volume.

But COPY command always searches for the source files inside the host machine by default.

Is there a way to change that behaviour?

My current Dockerfile.

```
# build docker. 
FROM node:19 AS PACKER

WORKDIR /home/canvas
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
RUN yarn build-only

COPY /home/canvas/dist static_web/canvas

// I want the ^ above line to copy from CONTAINER into the volume.
```

I tried using reading over the COPY documenation and found some ways of using volume mount in the docker-compose level to move the files. But would prefer if this can be done at the Dockerfile level.

Even compose level solutions are welcome, if its not possible via docker run level.

Comment: You can't. The `COPY` command is only used to populate files in a container image. Volumes during the build process are ephemeral.

Comment: So we can do it via docker compose?

Comment: What's actually in the volume?  Do you need the volume at all, or can you use the content that's in the image directly?  (Imagine the volume like an external USB drive; if you want files to be there, you generally need to copy them using a command like `cp`, but after the container starts.)

Comment: I want the build files generated for different containers and move the build files to one final web server to serve it.